# Wordpress get post meta not working in all cases

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to get the post meta of a post. It works fine for the case updated_post, but not for new_post and I just can't figure out why..

This is the function for the cases:

```
 function userpro_sc_new_post( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
global $userpro_social;
$exclude = userpro_sc_get_option('excluded_post_types');
if ($exclude != ''){
    $exclude_types = explode(',',$exclude);
} else {
    $exclude_types = array('nav_menu_item');
}
if (!in_array($post->post_type, $exclude_types )) {
    // new post
    if ( $new_status == 'publish' && $old_status != 'publish' ) {
        $user = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $userpro_social->log_action( 'new_post', $user->ID, $post->ID, $post->post_title, $post->post_type );
    }
    // updated post
    if ($new_status == 'publish' && $old_status == 'publish' ){
        $user = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $userpro_social->log_action( 'update_post', $user->ID, $post->ID, $post->post_title, $post->post_type );
    }
}
```

}

And this is the code to run in the cases:

```
function log_action($action, $user_id, $var1=null, $var2=null, $var3=null) {
global $userpro, $userpro_social;
$activity = get_option('userpro_activity');
$timestamp = current_time('timestamp');

$status = '';

switch($action){


    case 'new_post':
        $myId = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpex_post_video_oembed', true);
        $status .= $myId;

        break;

    case 'update_post':
        $myId = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpex_post_video_oembed', true);
        $status .= $myId;
        break;

        }
```

Like I said, update_post works so I can see the ID... new_post works actually but I can't get the ID here. Why?

I simplified the code to run a bit, but it is still the same issue.

Please help!

Comment: When you call the function, you're already sending `$post->ID` as the third parameter ( `$var1` in the receiving function ). Why not see if that one gives you the correct post ID instead of `get_the_ID()`?

Comment: does not work either :/ I don't know what is the problem here...

Comment: Strange thing is, that it works with the update post case

Comment: 2 things to check for the "new_post" case: is the post ID an actual ID or 0? If a number, which post / page does it match? And the second, does that new_post have that meta field set? You should see it in it's admin view under custom fields.

Comment: Yes it has the meta field set. In update post the id is the correct post id. In new post it just just nothing (null?)

Comment: The problem might be in the creating process of that new post, you should post the code for that. And/or show where that `userpro_sc_new_post` function gets attached.